# Open browser hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want this when I press ctrl+.

- if chrome is not running, open it up.
- if chrome is running, open the last window.

tried this

```
^.::
IfWinExist Google Chrome
    WinActivate, Google Chrome
else
    run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
return
```

but every time, it opens up a new windows for me.

Answer (score 5):

By default Autohotkey only matches on the beginning of the window title so your windows are not being found because they are of the format `New Tab - Google Chrome`

What you need to use is the [`SetTitleMatchMode`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm) command which can specify to match on *any* part of the window title instead of the beginning. By default this option is set to "1".

```
SetTitleMatchMode, MatchMode

One of the following digits or the word RegEx:

1: A window's title must start with the specified WinTitle to be a match.
2: A window's title can contain WinTitle anywhere inside it to be a match.
3: A window's title must exactly match WinTitle to be a match.
```

So what you are looking for is `SetTitleMatchMode 2` to make your script:

```
^.::
SetTitleMatchMode 2
IfWinExist Google Chrome
    WinActivate, Google Chrome
else
    run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
return
```

This works on my machine

Comment: thanks! now, how do you solve this similar one? http://superuser.com/questions/748819/ahk-running-url-as-standalone-program-workaround-needed

Comment: "This works on my machine" I automatically assume it won't work every time I read this ¯\_(ツ)_/¯