# AHK running url as standalone program - workaround needed

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I created this program

```
^+l::
IfWinExist Toggl
    WinActivate, Toggl
else
    run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -app=https://www.toggl.com/app/#timer
return
```

But the problem is that I use Toggl as a Chrome App and there are some issues.

- when the toggl timer is run and simply started, it works fine.
- when the toggl timer is off and you select "Continue" on a task the window title changes from "Toggl" to the task name and the script no longer matches on `Toggl`.

All my other programs, like RTM and Google Calendar have their names "appended" so that the script above always works.

How can I solve this using some clever temporary hack (workaround)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have to either rename your tasks to include "Toggl" in them somehow (and edit them out if you are sending them to clients) or assign it to a project called "Toggl" .  Neither of these seems overly practical though.

Otherwise you need to complain to the Toggl designers and tell them that rather than change the window/tab title to the task name they should be more consistant and either use "Toggl" for everything or "Toggl - (taskName)" as the format for their tabs.

I could see this also being fixed by a Greasemonkey script or Userscript running in Chrome that keeps the window title permanently at "Toggl" for that site but I do not know enough about Userscripts to create one.

If you are willing to give userscripts a shot then [this one](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/24034) seems to be a good start.

Comment: The userscript would basically be a one-liner: `window.title = 'Toggl - ' + window.title;`. Of course, the URL matching clause has to be designed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `SetTitleMatchMode 2` to the top of your script so that the window's title can contain WinTitle anywhere inside it to be a match.

Docs: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/SetTitleMatchMode.htm